# Workflow does not start on first item of the calendar day

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow

I have a very strange behaviour of a workflow in a document library. The SPD workflow is set to automatically start on creation. However, it does not start on the first uploaded document of a calendar day. It will start for every next created item. There is only one (non-custom) content type.

This problem appeared in SP2010 and continues after the migration to SP2013.

Comment: If it does not occur in a newly created Library it might nog be worth investigating why the Library got corrupted

Comment: @DannyEngelman Well, seems like I leave it like this... Strange behaviour anyhow.